# Fill holes holes/area in a binary image using OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have below preprocessed rice image. I want to fill the rice with black color and then perform the inverse operation to find contours. I am trying to use Erosion/Dilation operation but not working. Below is the code snippet I am using.

First I used shadow removal algorithm then used adaptive thresholding which gives the Input image. Now, I want to change the Input image to the output image.

Original Image:

[image]

Input Image:

[image: Input Image]

Required Output Image:

[image: Output Image]

Code Snippet:

```py
oposite = cv2.bitwise_not(img)

#Erosion
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.dilate(des,kernel,iterations = 1)
erosion = cv2.bitwise_not(erosion)
im_out = oposite + erosion

cv2.imshow("output", im_out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: What is 'des' image? You should invert your image first and then do a dilation and that should work. You may have to play around a bit with the kernel size.

Comment: Your “desired output” is the original image. You applied a non-linear transformation that cannot be undone. Thus you cannot retrieve the original image from the transformed one.

Comment: 'des' is 'opposite image'. Its typo error. Is there a way to use floodfill?

Comment: Flood fill would fill the holes in between the rice as well. Your best bet would be to detect the kernels and then draw them as filled shapes.

Comment: Please post the original image too.

Comment: Added original Image also. First I used the shadow removal and then adaptive thresholding to the original image, which gives the input image. Now, I want to change the input image to the required output image. Ultimate objective is to find out the contours.

Comment: @RajatHada I added an answer. Please let me know if it solved your problem, and if not, why. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an HSV mask by using the [`cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#gga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0aa4a7f0ecf2e94150699e48c79139ee12) flag in the [`cv2.cvtColor()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) method, and by using the [`cv2.inRange()`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981) method. I basically changed the maximum saturation value from `255` to `100`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("rice.jpg")
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper = np.array([179, 100, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

---

If you're looking to make the grains thinner, you can turn down the maximum hue value, from `179` to, say,`111`, along with the maximum saturation value at `100`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("rice.jpg")
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 0, 0])
upper = np.array([111, 100, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(img_hsv, lower, upper)
cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: it solves the problem :). I will check this approach with images which has more shadow.